# R plot: How to control distance between horizontal axis and lower column?

Tags: r, plot, axis

I have produced the following graph with this code:

```
png(file = "/home/tania/Desktop/internship_graph_mount/Results/bp.enrich.humanonly.top.stemness.png", width = 50*300, height = 60*300, res = 300)
par(mar=c(20, max(nchar(colnames(humanonlya)))+75, 20, 5))
barplot(humanonlya, horiz = T, beside=T, las=1, space = c(60/ncol(humanonlya),60/ncol(humanonlya)), col=colorRampPalette(c("red"))(n=1), cex.names=4.5, axes=F, xlim=c(0,10))
title(main = list("Biological Processes - human only", cex = 5), adj= 0, line=-1)
axis(side=1, at=seq(from=0,to = 10, by=2),cex = 5,lwd=4, xlab="-log10(FDR)", xlim=c(0,10), cex.axis=2.5, mgp=c(2,1,0))
dev.off()
```

[image]

I would like to bring the horizontal axis closer to the lower column.
How could I do that?

Comment: don't plot it with `barplot` but add it afterwards with `axis` and use parameter `line` to control where you want it

Comment: I added afterwards, and also tried changing line valie, but it didn't work...

Comment: please provide a [mcve] so it can be easier to help

Comment: for example, `barplot(1:5, horiz=TRUE, axes=FALSE); axis(1, line=-3)` will draw the axis inside the lower bar... In your call to `axis` you're not setting `line` value

Comment: you were right! i though line could only have -1, 0 and 1, but with -10 it worked fine. thank you!